# Form not uploading imageField in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm following an online course about Django.

I need to upload an image via a form but it doesn't work.

My form is in blog/contact and when I submit it goes back to blog/ without saving the for, also I can see the that form is bound= false and valid = false after submitting.

If anyone can help me ?

Here is my code :

```
# views.py 
def nouveau_contact(request):
    sauvegarde = False
    #il ne faut pas oublier le request.FILES sinon ça ne marche pas
    form = NouveauContactForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    print ("erreur : ")
    print(form.is_valid)
    if form.is_valid():
        contact = Contact()
        contact.nom = form.cleaned_data["nom"]
        contact.adresse = form.cleaned_data["adresse"]
        contact.photo = form.cleaned_data["photo"]
        contact.save()
        sauvegarde = True

    return render(request, 'blog/contact.html', {
        'form': form,
        'sauvegarde': sauvegarde
    })

# forms.py
class NouveauContactForm(forms.Form):
    nom = forms.CharField()
    adresse = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    photo = forms.ImageField()

# Media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

I am using anaconda and I have already downloaded pillow

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 
I actually just forgot the action in the form -_-

Answer (score 0):

you must use upload_to in ImageField in model. the 'path' in upload_to is use for path of image in media_root.

```
# views.py 
def nouveau_contact(request):
sauvegarde = False
#il ne faut pas oublier le request.FILES sinon ça ne marche pas
form = NouveauContactForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
print ("erreur : ")
print(form.is_valid)
if form.is_valid():
    contact = Contact()
    contact.nom = form.cleaned_data["nom"]
    contact.adresse = form.cleaned_data["adresse"]
    contact.photo = form.cleaned_data["photo"]
    contact.save()
    sauvegarde = True

return render(request, 'blog/contact.html', {
    'form': form,
    'sauvegarde': sauvegarde
})

# forms.py
class NouveauContactForm(forms.Form):
    nom = forms.CharField()
    adresse = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    photo = forms.ImageField(upload_to='path')
# Media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the model has already this param set and upload_to doesn't go in a form.